# How to configure local issuer certificate in Wamp using OpenSSL in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel-5

Am trying to send SMS Locally with Nexmo but i configured my Wamp server to use OpenSSL but when i try sending, i get this error.

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Am sending the message in a route from my `web.php` like this,

```
Route::get( '/sms/send/{to}', function(\ Nexmo\Client $nexmo, $to){
     $message = $nexmo->message()->send([
        'to' => $to,
        'from' => env('NEXMO_NUMBER'),
        'text' => 'Sending SMS from Laravel. Woohoo!'
    ]);
    Log::info('sent message: ' . $message['message-id']);
});
```

Need help of how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: https://github.com/nexmo/nexmo-php#troubleshooting

> Some users have issues making requests due to the following error:
>
> > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'
>
> This is due to some PHP installations not shipping with a list of trusted CA certificates. This is a system configuration problem, and not specific to either cURL or Nexmo.
>
> IMPORTANT: In the next paragraph we provide a link to a CA certificate bundle. Nexmo do not guarantee the safety of this bundle, and you should review it yourself before installing any CA bundle on your machine.
>
> To resolve this issue, download a list of trusted CA certificates (e.g. the curl bundle) and copy it on to your machine. Once this is done, edit php.ini and set the curl.cainfo parameter:
>
> ```
> Linux/MacOS
> curl.cainfo = "/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem"
> Windows
> curl.cainfo = "C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
> ```

Comment: My appreciations @Jim